# How to extract the id from googlemap addmarker()

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use the JQuery google map api and put some makers on my map. 
This is the code like

```
$("#map").googleMap();
$("#map").addMarker({
    coords: [48.895651, 2.290569], // GPS coords
    url: 'http://www.tiloweb.com', // Link to redirect onclick (optional)
    id: 'marker1' // Unique ID for your marker
}).addClass("clickit");
```

right now, I meet a problem that how to get the id: 'marker1' in the addMarker() method when I want to use onclick event like this

```
$(".clickit").on('click', function(event) {
    //Get the id: 'marker1' here
  });
```

Comment: show your  addMarker  and  googleMap function

Comment: I use CDN <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.googlemap/1.5/jquery.googlemap.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

Try to store markers in a global variable:

```
//global variable: 
var = markers[];  

//code: 
$("#map").googleMap();

//declare a local variable to store markers:
var marker = $("#map").addMarker({
    coords: [48.895651, 2.290569], // GPS coords
    url: 'http://www.tiloweb.com', // Link to redirect onclick (optional)
    id: 'marker1' // Unique ID for your marker
}).addClass("clickit");

//store local in a global variable: 
markers.push(marker);
```

then, just listen to the event:

```
$(".clickit").on('click', function(event) {
   console.log(marker.id);

  });
```